# Creating a plain text document window in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text, export, document

I have seen many questions asking how to export a file from Chrome but I have not found a good answer.

I have written a Chrome Application (**Legacy** Packaged Application) in which I am getting some data for the user. I just need to create some text in a Chrome window that the user can save to a file. The text would be tab-delimited text. If I use code such as what I show below then Chrome will not save the data; the Save As command is either disabled or does nothing. If we try to view the source (for diagnostic purposes at least) then Chrome crashes. Is there a way to create a window with text in it that can be saved? Or if there is a way to export a file then that would be better.

I have seen the filesystem API but as best as I understand it, it must either execute in a server or 
requires Chrome to be started with a special option. That makes the filesystem API too impractical.

I realize that a possible alternative is to create XML instead of plain text. I will offer XML as an alternative but I also want to provide plain text data.

This is a sample of the code I am using to create a window with text in it:

```
var w = window.open("BlankPage.html", "_blank", "menubar=yes", false);
var d = w.document;
d.open('text/plain', 'replace');
d.charset = "utf-8";
d.write("Hello");
d.close();
```

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/downloadify

Comment: Do you mean https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify? It says "for online use only".

Comment: That just means you can't run it from `file://`

Comment: I think it does not **just** mean not from file://. Regardless, it must work for a Chrome Application. Are you sure Downloadify works in a Chrome Application? Unless you know otherwise, "for online use only" means it won't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a Chrome Extension download a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845215/making-a-chrome-extension-download-a-file)

Comment: Totally different. In that, the file is being downloaded from the server ("will download a mp3 file **off a website**").

Comment: Read the answer; in that question, the OP already has the data locally.  That answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: That other question is misleading since the original question says "will download a mp3 file off a website". It makes it difficult to find. Assuming that will work for large files, then yes, that looks promising. I wish **my** question was better understood initially, the part where I said Chrome Application.

Comment: If the other answer requires additional permissions then I cannot use it since my application must be a legacy packaged application; it will not work as a non-legacy packaged application. I can get the blob to work outside my app but not in my app.

Comment: One of the answers to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338640/document-opentext-plain-formatting-ignored-in-webkit-safari-chrome) is to prefix the document content with the long-ago-obsoleted <PLAINTEXT> tag (still supported by at least Chrome in 2016).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use **Filesaver.js** in my Chrome extension to download a backup of the archive as a txt file.

Quoting from its README file:

> FileSaver.js is the solution to saving files on the client-side, and is perfect for webapps that need to generate files, or for saving sensitive information that shouldn't be sent to an external server.

FileSaver.js GitHub: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Demo: http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Comment: Thank you. It is wonderful when something works. This is the first time I have gotten something useful from a question I asked in Stackoverflow.