# jQuery/Javascript create a text file for user download

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form on my website that creates output for the user based on the input.
I want to create a text file with this output for the user to download (with browser download prompt, no security problems).

Is there a way to do this with Javascript/jQuery without using PHP to create the file on the server first?

Can I use some kind of Javascript object to serve as a dummy-file so that the user can download it (to solve the problem that there isn't a real txt file for the user to download from the server)?

Comment: Only with Javascript or JQuery it's not possible i think. You need server side script

Comment: For older browsers (and simple plaintext files) you can open a window in that document mode. Take a look at this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338640/document-opentext-plain-formatting-ignored-in-webkit-safari-chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338640/document-opentext-plain-formatting-ignored-in-webkit-safari-chrome)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by using [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=blobbuilder), [polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js)). Check out this [example by @UselessCode](https://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/qm5AG/):

```js
(function () {
var textFile = null,
  makeTextFile = function (text) {
    var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});

    // If we are replacing a previously generated file we need to
    // manually revoke the object URL to avoid memory leaks.
    if (textFile !== null) {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
    }

    textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

    return textFile;
  };


  var create = document.getElementById('create'),
    textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');

  create.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
    link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
    link.style.display = 'block';
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<textarea id="textbox">Type something here</textarea> <button id="create">Create file</button> <a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
```

Comment: There's a `Blob` polyfill for browsers that don't support it: https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js